# Ajax success data use in laravel php foreach

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I got ajax data, now I want to use the data in PHP for each function, I need to use the data to again MySQL query and for each,

My ajaxcode:

```
<script>
filter_data();

function filter_data()
{
    $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
    var action = 'fetch_data';
    var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
    var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
    var brand = get_filter('brand');
    var category = get_filter('category');
    var discount = get_filter('discount');

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('/ajaxFilterProduct') }}",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            action: action, 
            minimum_price: minimum_price, 
            maximum_price: maximum_price, 
            brand: brand, 
            category: category, 
            discount: discount
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.filter_data').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

What i want in laravel blade:

```
@foreach($data as $data)
    echo $data->id;
@endforeach
```

My laravel controller:

```
<?php
public function Product_filterBy_Ajax(Request $request) {
    $query = DB::table('products')->where('available', '=', "Yes");

    $minPrice = $request->minimum_price;
    $maxPrice = $request->maximum_price;
    //$query->where([  ['p_price', '>=', $minPrice],  ['p_price', '<=', $maxPrice], ]);

    $query->whereBetween('p_price', [$minPrice, $maxPrice]);

    $brand = $request->brand;

    if (!empty($brand)) {
        $collection = collect($brand);
        $query->whereIn('p_com_name_dis', $collection);
    }

    $category = $request->category;

    if (!empty($category)) {
        $collection = collect($category);
        $query->whereIn('p_sub_type', $collection);
    }

    $discount = $request->discount;

    if (!empty($discount)) {
        $collection = collect($discount);
        $query->whereIn('p_discount', $collection);
    }

    $result = $query->get();
    $count_result = $result->count();

    return $result;
    // if ($count_result > 0) {

    //  //return View::make("wecommerce/products_filter", ["jobs" => $generatedData]);
    //   return view('wecommerce/products_filter', compact('result'));

    // } //==end if

    //dd($result);

}  //==END FILTER PRODUCT==//
?>
```

Comment: please add your blade file.

Comment: … and an actual question and/or problem description. Please go read [ask].

Comment: i am new here. i want to know how to use ajax success data that i return from my controller.(data is successfully returned) i can use the data in html but i need to use the data in php foreach function. how to creat success data to php variable that is use able in php foreach function.

Comment: Please update your question to include all relevant information. If you write it in comments, other users might miss the information.

Comment: You can't use data returned from an ajax request (which is javascript) in a PHP loop. Javscript (client side) and PHP (server side) are two completely different languages that lives/gets executed in two completely different environments. PHP gets executed on the server. Then the server sends the result of that to the client, where your javascript is being executed. Also, that's just a loop. You can just as easily do that in javascript directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use each function in jquery as

```
   success: function(result) {
     $.each(data, function(v) {
                    var val = data[v];
                    formoption += "<option value='" + val['id'] + "'>" + val[
                        'name'] + "</option>";
                });
```